# Deeply struggling with the functions sections in Rosen's book on discrete math. Any good alternatives, or additional exercises?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I've been having lots of fun with Rosen's "discrete mathematics and its practical applications"  so far, but I've hit a dead end with functions. I managed to do all of the exercises up until about 39 on section 2.3 (functions), where I'm now stuck. It isn't even a sudden thing - I gradually got worse and worse as I got here, and now I've come to a complete halt. I'm barely crawling through the sequences section so I won't even start doing exercises there any time soon.

As for functions, I've reread the section over and over and over again but it seems like I'm not grasping the material well enough to make any progress with the exercises past a certain point. Rereading the previous sections of chapter 2 didn't help either.

This leads me to conclude that I need more expansive reading material about this particular area of discrete mathematics. Can you recommend me something of the sort?

Also, I tried to get into calculus, and failed utterly at it, leading me to conclude that I need to get back to precalculus, probably to get better at playing around with functions. Do you think that my function-related deficiencies from there are part of the problem here?

Comment: There are many books on elemntary topics... Maybe useful Keith Devlin, [Sets Functions and Logic (CRC, 3rd ed. 2004)](https://books.google.it/books?id=gUb7CAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Seems interesting, though the talk of "post-calculus" scares me. I hope he means "post-school-grade calculus" and not "what comes after calculus III".